# JqGrid EditForm values not loaded properly

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My JqGrid Edit Form behaves interestingly. It Loads with certain rows. when i select edit, all values get preloaded in the form  except a select tag (**srf_sizeremarks**)

```
 var srfgrid = $("#srfArticletbl"); 
    srfgrid.jqGrid({ 
                 datatype: "json",
                 url:"/Myelclass/SrfinsertArticle.do", 
                 mtype: "GET", 
                 autoencode: true,
                 postData: {
                     sampleno: function (){return $("#srf_sampleno").val();},
                 },
                 colNames:['ArticleID','ArticleShForm',....,'Srfarticleid'],  
                 colModel :[  
                            .........
                            //srf_sizeremarks not loading
                             {name:'srf_sizeremarks', index:'srf_sizeremarks', width:40, align:'center',  editable:true, hidden: true, 
                                edittype:'select',
                                editoptions: { 
                                  dataUrl:'/Myelclass/PrfAutocomplete.do?action=sizerem',
                                  type:"GET",
                                  buildSelect: function(data) {
                                    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                                            var s = '<select style="width: 520px">';
                                            if (response && response.length) {
                                                s += '<option value="0">--- Select Article Type ---</option>';
                                                for (var i = 0, l=response.length; i<l ; i++) {
                                                  var ri = response[i].value;
                                                  s += '<option value="'+ri+'">'+ri+'</option>';
                                                }
                                            }
                                       return s + "</select>";
                                   },
                                 } ,
                                editrules:{edithidden:true},
                                formoptions:{rowpos: 3, colpos: 3}, 
                            },
```

And the Edit Form Code is

```
//Edit 
      top: 150,
      left: 200,
      width : 750,
      recreateForm: true,
      beforeShowForm: function(formid) { 
          //alert("In Edit Form "); //if i uncomment this it works perfectly
          //Size Calculation
          var sizec = $("#srf_size").val();
          var temp = sizec.indexOf(' ');
          $("#srf_size").val(sizec.substring(0, temp));
          $("#srf_sizeremarks").val(sizec.substring(temp+1));
          $("#tr_srf_price").hide();
      },

      closeAfterEdit: true,
      reloadAfterSubmit: true,
```

If i add an **alertbox** in **beforeShowForm** it works perfectly. I understand that this is *nowhere related to alertbox* but i want to know where i went wrong. Kindly throw some lights.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the value of `'srf_sizeremarks'` should already contains the select value which need be selected. I'm not sure why you need to change the value by usage additional code `$("#srf_sizeremarks").val(valueToselect);` inside of `beforeShowForm`.

If you use `editoptions` with `dataUrl` then jqGrid first creates Add/Edit form with **empty** `<select>` and starts asynchronous Ajax request to `dataUrl`. So `beforeShowForm` can/will work **before** the `<select>` will be filled. So you can't use `$("#srf_sizeremarks").val(valueToselect);`.

I think that the simplest way will be modification of `buildSelect` callback. It build `<select>` with list of `<option>`. You can move the code of `beforeShowForm` into `buildSelect` callback and add `selected="selected"` attribute to the item if `ri===sizec.substring(temp+1)`. It should fix the problem if the original value from `'srf_sizeremarks'` column don't equal one of the options. If you do have the original value from `'srf_sizeremarks'` column which equal a value of the option then it will be selected.

Alternatively you can include

```
setTimeout(function(){
    ...
    // the code from beforeShowForm sould be here
    $("#srf_sizeremarks").val(valueToselect); // sizec.substring(temp+1)
    ...
}, 50);
```

**inside of** `buildSelect`. In the way you will be sure that you will select the value *after* the select was built and after the original value from `'srf_sizeremarks'` column (if any exist) was selected. So it should work too.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, and sorry for the late response. From the second paragraph of your answer i understand where i went wrong. Will check and come back to you

Comment: @Wahab: You are welcome! It would be interesting for me to know which way you choose and which one will fix your problem.